# error in system command to output

Tags: perl, command, system, output

I want to run ext software (hmmer) commands through perl in a loop for input files (in linux).

I used this line

```
system "hmmbuild  $outfile $files";
```

where $outfile is my output file and $files in my input files. `hmmbuild` is the command for the ext software.

When I run the program it gives me error code for the output file **GLOB(0x1b94b220)**.

Can any one help me where I am wrong and how can it be corrected?

I tried exec command also with back tick and brackets.

This is the exact output message i got. How can  I print my result to output file ($outfile)?

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `hmmbuild --amino GLOB(0x11eb3220) aproNOG00001'
```

script goes here..

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use Bio::AlignIO;
 use Bio::Align::AlignI;

 my $allfiles= 'allfilenames_alpha_hmms.txt';
  system "module load hmmer/3.1b1";
print "loaded hmmer\n";
 open(FIH, $allfiles);
 while ($min=<FIH>)
{ chomp($min);   my @pats=split " ",$min;
     foreach my $files(@pats)  {

     print $files; print "\n";

open(my $outfile,  '>',"$prefix.hmm");  

system "hmmbuild --amino $outfile $files";

print $outfile;
print "file saved\n";

# }
  }
 }
  print "\n\n\n\t   ###\tDONE\t###   \n\n";
```

Comment: Tag your question with the language you are using, Perl in this case.

Comment: Also, GLOB is not an error code, that's your result. You need to read as documentation and/or examples.

Comment: `$outfile` is not a file, it's a variable. Its value can't be a file. Those are found on disks. It probably should be a file *name*, but it appears to be a file *handle*.

Comment: You probably used `open` using `$outfile` as a file handle (the first argument).  More than likely your program wants a file name in `$outfile`, not a file handle.

Comment: To be clear, while it most likely wants a file name, it most definitely doesn't want a file handle. It's impossible to pass anything but strings as arguments to a program.

Comment: Unless you post your perl program, people can only guess, not give you any meaningful hints.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm, I wouldn't say explaining the problem quite precisely and giving the most likely solution is "not giving meaningful hints".

Comment: i tried to post the program. it says some format of 4 space. and I am new to this site. i will try to post it..

Comment: You should `use strict;` -- always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i print my result to output file ($outfile)

I take it `hmmbuild` expects a path to a file? Pass the path to the file rather than what's in `$outfile`.

```
system "hmmbuild --amino $prefix.hmm $files";
```

Comment: So remove the `open` and change to `system "hmmbuild --amino $prefix.hmm $files";`

Comment: ... except `$prefix` doesn't seem to be defined.